# Screenshot of an alert, iOS, Swift

Tags: ios, swift, screenshot, uialertview

I am taking a screenshot when I show an alert, this works in taking a screenshot but when it is saved to the camera roll it has only captured the screen behind the alert and hasn't included the alert in the screenshot.

Is it possible to do this?

Below is my code.

```
func ScreenShot() {
    //Create the UIImage
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.frame.size, true, 0)
    guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }
    view.layer.render(in: context)
    guard let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() else { return }
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    //Save it to the camera roll
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil)
}
```

caling it here.

```
func alertShow() {

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "ALERT!!!", message: "Message stuff", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)


    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { action in

        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toMainInfoVC", sender: nil)

    }))

    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    ScreenShot()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need the complete layer of the key window

```
let layer = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.layer
let scale = UIScreen.main.scale
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(layer.frame.size, false, scale);

layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
```

Comment: Thank you for this, this helped, It still didn't do it but it did screenshot everything else so I knew I had to place the screenshot trigger in a different place which ended up being in the completion of the alert present. Then it worked fine, Thank you again

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems with your code.  First you are immediately trying to take a snapshot before the alert has finished being presented.  You shoudl call your snapshot function in the compeletion handler of present:

`self.present(alert, animated: true) {
            self.ScreenShot()
        }`

Second you are only rendering the current view, and the alert is not a subview of your viewcontroller's view.  You want to render the entire window hierarchy instead:

`view.window?.layer.render(in: context)`

Comment: Thank you for your answer on this Josh,  I had worked with the answer above and found that I needed to change the position of calling the function and ended up putting it in the completion of the present alert. But spot on with this, Thak you for your time on it.